# SQL Workbench + PostgreSQL: how to show execution plans?

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, sql-workbench-j

I have recently started using SQL Workbench instead of pgAdmin to run queries on a PostgreSQL 9.3 server.

Is there any way to show the execution plan? I looked everywhere but only managed to find an option to do it with Oracle, not PostgreSQL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as in `psql`

Simply run:

```
explain (verbose true, analyze true)
select some_column
from some_table
where another_column = 42
```

The execution plan will then be shown as the result of that query.

The manual contains an example on how you can put this into a macro and run this automatically:

http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/macros.html#executable-macros

Comment: But there is no way of showing it graphically like pgAdmin does, or is there? At the risk of going slightly off-topic, what client would you recommend for PostgreSQL? I'm willing to buy a commercial one like SQL Maestro if it's really good. Thanks a lot